# Qt - Prevent menubar from grabbing focus after Alt pressed on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

In my application, I need to change my mouse cursor and do some stuff differently once the `Alt` key is pressed, and go back to the normal cursor and normal behavior once the `Alt` key is released.

Everything works fine on Mac OS, while the `Alt`-pressing event moves the focus to the menubar on Windows (native Windows behavior), which results in unexpected behaviors of my cursor-changing desire.

So the question is: how to disable this Windows feature (code-wise in Qt of course) and always pass the `Alt` key press event to the application itself instead of the menubar.

Comment: FTR, I [reported a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77355) on this problem, about focus getting stuck in menu after Alt key press-release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SH_MenuBar_AltKeyNavigation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StyleHint-enum) style hint responsible for menubar selection after Alt pressed. You need to subclass [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) and override `styleHint` method like this:

```
class MenuStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint stylehint, const QStyleOption *opt, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
    {
        if (stylehint == QStyle::SH_MenuBar_AltKeyNavigation)
            return 0;

        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(stylehint, opt, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

Then, set custom style to application.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setStyle(new MenuStyle());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped solve the problem. Well noted.